# Reuse Junit asserts in different classes

Tags: java, junit, reusability

I have some tests that made asserts in JsonObject that are returned for different endpoints, like this:

```
JsonElement product = asJsonObject.get("product");
JsonElement type = product.getAsJsonObject().get("type");
Assert.assertEquals(ProductType.PRODUCT_1.name(), type.getAsString());
JsonElement name = product.getAsJsonObject().get("name");
Assert.assertEquals("name", name.getAsString());
```

This a lot of Java code, right? There are more than one endpoint that return the same Json and a I need to do the same assert to guarantee the expected result.

But I'm trying to find a way to reuse this code above. Obviously,I can do something like this:

```
new AssertProduct(asJsonObject.get("product")).assert(type, name);
```

And:

```
class AssertProduct {

    private JsonElement product;

    AssertProduct(JsonElement product) {
        this.product = product;
    {

    boolean assert(String name, String type) {
        JsonElement type = product.getAsJsonObject().get("type");
        Assert.assertEquals(type, type.getAsString());
        JsonElement name = product.getAsJsonObject().get("name");
        Assert.assertEquals(name, name.getAsString());
    }

}
```

But... this is a good approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: I would separate them so you can do `AssertProduct(asJsonObject.get("product")).ofType(x).ofName(y)`

Comment: IMHO it is a good approach.

Comment: @vikingsteve nice. Would you mind to make an answer with this suggestion? I will you mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a flexible way to assert the expected values of the json object, based on the builder pattern:

```
public class AssertProduct {

    private JsonElement product;

    public AssertProduct(JsonElement product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public static AssertProduct withProduct(JsonElement product) {
        return new AssertProduct(product);
    }

    AssertProduct ofName(String name) {
        Assert.assertEquals(name, product.getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());
        return this;
    }

    AssertProduct ofType(String type) {
        Assert.assertEquals(type, product.getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString());
        return this;
    }
}
```

The usage then looks like this:

```
AssertProduct.withProduct(checkMe).ofName("some-name").ofType("some-type");
```